# org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration deprecated in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

In my web application, I am using Spring-Data and JPA/Hibernate.My senario is I have to create separate schema company wise.so I am taking username,password and companycode while login .Taking company code will help to find out scheme for that company.My database schema will change according to user logged in so in order to do that I have written hibernate interceptor as describe by http://blog.krecan.net/2009/01/24/spring-managed-hibernate-interceptor-in-jpa but since it is using org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration which is going to be deprecated so can anyone tell me other alternative way ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693139/encountered-a-deprecated-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceprovider)

Answer (score 1):

> `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` has been deprecated in this release
>   and `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration` has been deprecated for
>   some time now. Both will get removed before 4.0.0 goes Final. We are
>   still planning exactly what the replacement for
>   `org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration` will look like, but it too has
>   been deprecated in the meantime

(the recommended way to build an `EntityManagerFactory` has always been via `javax.persistence.Persistence` anyway).

I am referring [this blog post](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateCore400Alpha3Release)