# Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

when you use spring & Hibernate, have you ever met a log warning that says

> WARN  o.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence - HHH015016: Encountered a
>   deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
>   [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
>   [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.

How to handle that? Thank you for any answer.

Comment: use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead ?

Comment: It's a Hibernate bug. Supposedly fixed in newer versions: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8625

Comment: Not fixed in latest stable.

Comment: I get this in `4.3.4.Final`. Bootstrapping with `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Foo")` and nothing else.

Comment: It still a bug in 4.3.5, see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9141

Answer (score 34):

It should be

```
org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
```

Have a look at [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/).

> **Deprecated.**
>
> Use [HibernatePersistenceProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/) instead

Comment: cause of the problem? how to fix the problem? What files should I change in spring configuration?

Comment: @riship89 You have to change the `persistence.xml`. @AaronHall Thats wrong. I wrote to use `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` instead of `javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider`.

Answer (score 15):

If you are working with Spring Data JPA and Java Configuration, you will be able to solve it, adding the following code in your Entity Manager Factory:

**factory.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());**

```
@Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {

      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
      vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      **factory.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());**
      factory.setPackagesToScan("com.company.appname.persistence.domain");
      factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

      factory.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
      factory.afterPropertiesSet();

      return factory.getObject();
    }
```

You will find a good example of Hibernate configuration with Spring Data JPA here: http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/3/

Answer (score 9):

For users who are not using SPRING:

We can replace the standard *javax.persistence* bootstrapping by a Hibernate specific one.

Old:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
    PERSISTENCE_UNIT, props );
```

New:

```
PersistenceProvider provider = new HibernatePersistenceProvider();
EntityManagerFactory emf = provider.createEntityManagerFactory(
   PERSISTENCE_UNIT, props);
```

The *deprecated* warnings should now be gone.
The problem was still present in *4.3.1.Final*. In *5.1.0.Final* it should be fixed.

Comment: :( too bad. Can't go to 5.1, it breaks all my naming strategies, and there's no funding for spending hours and hours messing with naming strategies...

Comment: I'm using Hibernate 4.3.8.Final and warnings are still there. However I managed to fix the issue with the suggested change in persistence.xml, plus the change recommended by this answer. I don't see the warnings anymore

Answer (score 8):

Had this problem while working with JPA's Entity Manager in Spring context, having transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" in persistence.xml.

It's not always a bug. I actually had the wrong provider configured.

I just changed the provider in persistence.xml from

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

to

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

and it works fine.

Notice that the package changed from **EJB** to **JPA**

Comment: Please stop commenting that it doesn't work for you.

I didn't said my comment is always a solution. It is a solution sometimes. My comment was just a heads up for checking this, and I thought it may be handy. As I said : "It's not always a bug. I actually had the wrong provider configured." Maybe it's a common mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You get this message because the class `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` is deprecated. Under my `persistence.xml` file I found the provider class had `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` and I changed it to `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` as mentioned in the stacktrace warning message.

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="personPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>Person</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
        ....
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: For those in xml spring configuration see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520602/spring-data-jpa-no-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-is-defined-injection-of-a . The declaration is <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
    </property>

Answer (score 1):

After changing your `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` to `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` in the `persistence.xml`
Change also the `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency version, get the last version **5.2.10**.Final that fixed the bug. Here is:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.2.10.Final

it's worked for me

Comment: For sure it will work for all  versions greater then 5.x.x.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the reference to:

```
org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
```

but it didn't work.

Then I removed all the references to Hibernate 4.x jar libs, downloaded last version (5.2.7), then added this jar files and it finally works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a Has-A relationship and forgot to mention @Embedded then it will throw the same error.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named TEST
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Do mean the issue is at the Entity level?