# Use Hibernate Core instead of EnityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I was using Hibernate EntityManager dependecy in my earlier projects and it was working fine. Now I see it is deprecated in favour of Hibernate Core. However my project doesn't work with that dependency (it works with           *hibernate-entitymanager*).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>HibernateDocs_1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Im executing this code:

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("one");
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

and I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named one
```

JPA config:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="one">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hibernate" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="but" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Location of persistence.xml:

[image: project structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're still using the old provider.
Switch to the new one

```
<persistence-unit name="one">
   <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
   ...
```

Comment: Could you just point me to a place where I should have found this information?

Comment: Here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691252/error-deprecated-persistenceprovider-use-hibernatepersistenceprovider-instead