# Spring data jpa- No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined; Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing application using spring data jpa,hibernate,mysql,tomcat7,maven and it's create error.I'm  trying to figure it out but i failed.

error are  Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined; Injection of autowired dependencies failed

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initDbService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.wahid.cse.repository.RoleRepository org.wahid.cse.service.InitDbService.roleRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#c08f81' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#c08f81': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)


 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.wahid.cse.repository.RoleRepository org.wahid.cse.service.InitDbService.roleRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#c08f81' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#c08f81': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 22 more

 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#c08f81' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#c08f81': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 24 more
```

### here is my ApplicationContext.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="org.wahid.cse">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jba" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<bean id="emf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.wahid.cse.entity" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
    </property>

</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

### Here is pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.ferdous.wahid</groupId>
<artifactId>java-blog-aggregator</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>


<!-- Shared version number properties -->
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <apache.tiles>3.0.4</apache.tiles>
    <servlet-api-version>3.1.0</servlet-api-version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.31</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId> <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId> 
        <version>2.2.1</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring 
        Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use 
        Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define 
        this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
        spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, 
        spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection 
        Container and is generally always defined -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, 
        Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
        DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
        spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, 
        and iBatis. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) 
        Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, 
        JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
        Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
        Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
        web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
        Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet 
        Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and 
        TestNG This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for 
        the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

RoleRepository is

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.wahid.cse.entity.Role;

 public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer>{

 }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `RoleRepository`?

Comment: RoleRepository posted...

Comment: Thanks for that! I see you are using Spring Data JPA, but I don't see where you have configured it. Is there any Spring configuration that you haven't posted?

Comment: Changing bean id from "emf" to "entityManagerFactory" will solve the issue because Spring Data JPA looks for Bean named 'entityManagerFactory' by default. But if you really want to bind any NON-DEFAULT named bean as the entity manager factor, answer given by 'geoand' is the exact way with which you should change the things. Hope it help to clear the understanding as you have already resolved the issue :-)

Comment: I was able to solve this problem in my Mvc test classes by replacing `@WebMvcTest` with `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`

Comment: @forresthopkinsa I had the same error and your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Spring Data JPA by default looks for an EntityManagerFactory named `entityManagerFactory`. Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.x/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html#entityManagerFactoryRef%28%29) part of the Javadoc of `EnableJpaRepositories` or `Table 2.1` of the Spring Data JPA [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html).

That means that you either have to rename your `emf` bean to `entityManagerFactory` or change your Spring configuration to:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="your.package" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" />
```

(if you are using XML)

or

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="your.package", entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")`

(if you are using Java Config)

Comment: also if you had custom transaction manager bean name don't forget to set it.
For Java Config: `@EnableJpaRepositories(transactionManagerRef="myTransactionManagerBeanName") `

Answer (score 17):

Had this issue when migrated spring boot 1.5.2 to 2.0.4.
Instead of creating bean I've used `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in the main class and it solved my problem.

Comment: That's already included in `@SpringBootApplication`.

Answer (score 10):

In your application context, change the bean with id from `emf` to `entityManagerFactory`:

```xml
<bean id="emf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.wahid.cse.entity" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
    </property>

</bean>
```

To

```xml
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.wahid.cse.entity" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks. You solved my problem by following "In your application context, change the bean with id from emf to entityManagerFactory". Regards.

Comment: What we can use for Annotation based example? I'm facing extact issue

Comment: @javaHelper Look at geoand's answer above. He has shown one of the ways to fix the issue for Java config. If you are still unclear or face an issue, ask a new question and I can help you with it by providing the appropriate code (difficult to do that in a comment).

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue after migrating from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` ver. 1.5.7 to 2.0.2 (from old hibernate to hibernate 5.2). In my `@Configuration` class I injected `entityManagerFactory` and `transactionManager`.

```
//I've got my data source defined in application.yml config file, 
//so there is no need to configure it from java.
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    //JpaVendorAdapteradapter can be autowired as well if it's configured in application properties.
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    //Add package to scan for entities.
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.company.domain");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return txManager;
}
```

Also remember to add hibernate-entitymanager dependency to pom.xml otherwise EntityManagerFactory won't be found on classpath:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this is related to the newer version of spring boot plus using spring data JPA.
Just replace the `@Bean` annotation for `public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()`
to
`@Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")`

Determining the name of bean should solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It might help somebody.
For me none of the above solutions worked so I went into the folder where my project is situated deleted .idea folder, imported my project again and run - `mvn clean install.`
After this everything worked fine.
I am using IntellJ.

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case I seemed to have been missing the dependency

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

just updated the springboot version to 2.1.3 and it worked of me

Answer (score 0):

I migrated to spring boot 3.2 and could not run project due to such error in this discussion and found that bean must be named as **entityManagerFactory**

[Spring-boot: required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416927/spring-boot-required-a-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-that-could-not-be-foun)

```
@Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and got it resolved by deleting .m2 maven repo (C:\Users\user\ .m2)

Comment: what? How is that a solution?