# My Spring boot application failed to start: with error 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
Logs


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2017-05-10 22:20:52.172  INFO 4433 --- [           main] com.userModule.user_module.Application   : Starting Application on hiren-vostro with PID 4433 (/media/hiren/Study/workspace/user-module/target/classes started by hiren in /media/hiren/Study/workspace/user-module)
2017-05-10 22:20:52.210  INFO 4433 --- [           main] com.userModule.user_module.Application   : The following profiles are active: application.properties
2017-05-10 22:20:52.758  INFO 4433 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@15c43bd9: startup date [Wed May 10 22:20:52 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-10 22:21:01.766  INFO 4433 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$28cfbdfe] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-05-10 22:21:04.373  INFO 4433 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-10 22:21:04.515  INFO 4433 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-05-10 22:21:04.526  INFO 4433 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2017-05-10 22:21:05.046  INFO 4433 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-05-10 22:21:05.047  INFO 4433 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 12312 ms
2017-05-10 22:21:05.595  INFO 4433 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-05-10 22:21:05.607  INFO 4433 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-10 22:21:05.609  INFO 4433 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-10 22:21:05.609  INFO 4433 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-10 22:21:05.610  INFO 4433 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-10 22:21:06.130  WARN 4433 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#c6634d' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#c6634d': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2017-05-10 22:21:06.139  INFO 4433 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-05-10 22:21:06.326  INFO 4433 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-10 22:21:06.596 ERROR 4433 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.userModule.user_module.MainController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
```

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Below is code.
Application.java

```
package com.userModule.user_module;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
    }

}
```

MainController.java

```
    package com.userModule.user_module;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import com.userModule.user_module.AppUser; 
    import com.userModule.user_module.UserRepository;
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(path="/demo")
    public class MainController {


    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/add")
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String email){

        AppUser newUser = new AppUser();
        newUser.setName(name);
        newUser.setEmail(email);
        this.userRepository.save(newUser);

        return "Saved";
    }
}
```

AppUser.java

```
package com.userModule.user_module;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
@Entity
public class AppUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.userModule.user_module;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<AppUser, Long>{

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.userModule</groupId>
  <artifactId>user-module</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>user-module</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
 <build>
 <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.profiles.active=application.properties
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data jpa- No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined; Injection of autowired dependencies failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520602/spring-data-jpa-no-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-is-defined-injection-of-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing these dependencies from your pom.xml, as they are already pulled by spring-data-jpa

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I have a similar issue but I am not using any of those dependencies:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315919/spring-2-0-0-m4-required-a-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-that-could-not-be-f any idea here ? Thanks