# Spring Data JPA - Multiple EnableJpaRepositories

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, datasource

My application has multiple data sources , so i have created two data source configuration classes based on this  [URL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources) .

But while  running the spring boot  application am getting error

> Description:
> Field userDataRepo in com.cavion.services.UserDataService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
> Action:
> Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

From this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520602/spring-data-jpa-no-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-is-defined-injection-of-a) on StackOverflow helped me to figure out the issue.i need to specify the entityManagerFactoryRef on my JPA repositories .

But i have many repository classes some of them uses Entitymanager 'A' and some of them uses 'B' . my current spring boot application class is like this

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan("com.info.entity")
@ComponentScan({"com.info.services","com.info.restcontroller"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.info.repositories")
public class CavionApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CavionApplication.class, args);
}
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return args -> {

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }

    };
}}
```

I have given the EnableJpaRepositories on the spring boot class , so how can i configure multiple EnableJpaRepositories so that i can configure multiple entityManagerFactory ?

Please suggest the best  way to setup the multiple data sources .

Answer (score 99, accepted):

In order to let spring knows what `DataSource` is related to what `Repository` you should define it at the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation.  Let's assume that we have two entities, the `Servers` entity and the `Domains` entity and each one has its own Repo then each Repository has its own JpaDataSource configuration.

**1. Group all the repositories based on the Data Source that they are related to.  For example**

Repository for `Domains` entities (package: `org.springdemo.multiple.datasources.repository.domains`):

```
package org.springdemo.multiple.datasources.repository.domains;

import org.springdemo.multiple.datasources.domain.domains.Domains;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface DomainsRepository extends JpaRepository<Domains,Long> {
}
```

Repository for `Servers` entities (package: `org.springdemo.multiple.datasources.repository.servers`)

```
package org.springdemo.multiple.datasources.repository.servers;

import org.springdemo.multiple.datasources.domain.servers.Servers;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ServersRepository extends JpaRepository<Servers,Long> {
}
```

**2. For each JPA Data Soruce you need to define a configuration, in this example I show how to configure two different DataSources**

`Domains` Jpa Configuration: the relationship between the Data Source and the repository is defined in the `basePackages` value, that is the reason why is necessary to group the repositories in different packages depending on the entity manager that each repo will use.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "domainsEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "domainsTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"org.springdemo.multiple.datasources.repository.domains"}
        )
public class DomainsConfig {
```

`Servers` Data Source Configuration: as you can see the basePackages value has the package name of the `Servers` Repository , and also the values of `entityManagerFactoryRef` and `transactionManagerRef` are different in order to let spring separate each entityManager.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "serversEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "serversTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"org.springdemo.multiple.datasources.repository.servers"}
        )
public class ServersConfig {
```

**3. Set one Datasource as primary**

In order to avoid the error message: `Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:` just set one of the datasource as @Primary, in this example I select the `Servers` Datasource as primary:

```
@Bean("serversDataSourceProperties")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.servers")
public DataSourceProperties serversDataSourceProperties(){
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}



@Bean("serversDataSource")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.servers")
public DataSource serversDataSource(@Qualifier("serversDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties serversDataSourceProperties) {
    return serversDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}
```

If you need more information please see the full example for each configuration:

`Servers` JPA Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "serversEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "serversTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"org.springdemo.multiple.datasources.repository.servers"}
        )
public class ServersConfig {

    @Bean(name = "serversEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getServersEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                          @Qualifier("serversDataSource") DataSource serversDataSource){


        return builder
                .dataSource(serversDataSource)
                .packages("org.springdemo.multiple.datasources.domain.servers")
                .persistenceUnit("servers")
                .properties(additionalJpaProperties())
                .build();

    }

    Map<String,?> additionalJpaProperties(){
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        map.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        map.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        return map;
    }


    @Bean("serversDataSourceProperties")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.servers")
    public DataSourceProperties serversDataSourceProperties(){
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }



    @Bean("serversDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.servers")
    public DataSource serversDataSource(@Qualifier("serversDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties serversDataSourceProperties) {
        return serversDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "serversTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("serversEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory serversEntityManager){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(serversEntityManager);

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

`Domains` JPA Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "domainsEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "domainsTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"org.springdemo.multiple.datasources.repository.domains"}
        )
public class DomainsConfig {

    @Bean(name = "domainsEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getdomainsEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder
    ,@Qualifier("domainsDataSource") DataSource domainsDataSource){

        return builder
                .dataSource(domainsDataSource)
                .packages("org.springdemo.multiple.datasources.domain.domains")
                .persistenceUnit("domains")
                .properties(additionalJpaProperties())
                .build();

    }


    Map<String,?> additionalJpaProperties(){
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        map.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        map.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        return map;
    }


    @Bean("domainsDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.domains")
    public DataSourceProperties domainsDataSourceProperties(){
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }


    @Bean("domainsDataSource")
    public DataSource domainsDataSource(@Qualifier("domainsDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties domainsDataSourceProperties) {
        return domainsDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "domainsTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("domainsEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory domainsEntityManager){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(domainsEntityManager);

        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

In order to separate each datasource I put the configuration in the `application.properties` file, like this:

```
app.datasource.domains.url=jdbc:h2:mem:~/test
app.datasource.domains.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver


app.datasource.servers.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
app.datasource.servers.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/v?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
app.datasource.servers.username=myuser
app.datasource.servers.password=mypass
```

If you need more information please see the following documentation:

[Spring Documentation: howto-two-datasources](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources)

A similar example of how configure two different databases: [github example](https://github.com/tonym2105/samples/tree/master/boot-multidb-sample)

Comment: i tried this , but am getting error "Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' in your configuration." . initially i got error saying bean of type services couldnt find  i hope that that is because of the new Config classes are not loaded.so i have imported those two classes into the Main class  .after that i was able to execute the config class but getting the above mentioned error .

Comment: i was able to resolve the above issue by removing the  exclude of  HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration from Main class 
 . but  am getting new error while initializing entitymanagers    Description:
Method requestMappingHandlerMapping in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
 - ibDemoEntityManager: defined by method 'getIBDemoEntityManager' in IBDemoConfig- mwDemoEntityManager: defined by method 'getServersEntityManager' in MWDemoConfig

Comment: i was able to solve the issue by making the entitymanager of one of the class as primary

Comment: Ok, I also added that observation to make one of the datasource as primary.

Comment: I keep getting 'Not a managed type' for my entity classes while running the springboot project. Any ideas?

Comment: My code compiled and run, but when i am executing findAll() on @primary resource, i am getting org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException, could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet.

Comment: In Log i am getting relation 'xxx.abc' does not exist. but it exist in primary datasource. not in second. If i remove every configuration and run the same code on default it working fine. I want default as well as second data source.

Comment: Is this your article, or is someone just copy-pasting answers from stackoverflow on their website:
https://newbedev.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-enablejparepositories

Comment: @ADJenks unfortunately there are many websites that crawl and reformat StackOverflow Q&As, trying to disguise it as original content for profits.

Answer (score 3):

The answered provided by @Daniel C. is correct. Small correction/observation from my side.

- **@Primary** is not required if you don't want to mark any datasource as
  default one, otherwise necessary.
- If you are defining any of the *EntityManagerFactoryBean* with **@Bean** name as **entityManagerFactory** then it's better to mark it **@Primary** to avoid conflict.
- @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.servers")
  can be marked at class level instead of defining at method level.
- Better to return *HikariDataSource* as datasource if you using Spring
  Boot 2.x or higher version as it has been changed.
- Make sure you define exact property for **jdbc-url** which is being used by
  *HikariDataSource* to refer JDBC Connection URL.

Answer (score 1):

I just added a module aware multi database aware library for mysql in github.Some application properties need to be added and you are done .

Documentation and other details could be found at :-

https://github.com/yatharthamishra0419/spring-boot-data-multimodule-mysql