# Multiple Datasources

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, datasource

I have wired two datasources following examples for Oracle DB:

@Configuration
public class SpringConfigurationProperties extends DataSourceProperties {

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDatasource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("primaryDatasource")
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate primaryNpJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="gps.bulk.load.database")
public DataSource bulkLoadDatasource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("bulkLoadDatasource")
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate bulkLoadNpJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

}

But I am geting the following error on startup:

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker required a single bean, but 2 were found

Comment: looks like you have clashes with your datasources... so change @Qualifier("primaryDataSource") to "somethingDatasource"

Comment: May help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711250/connecting-to-multiple-database-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

I think i could reproduce this error:

`Parameter 1 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - myConfig: defined in file [...MyConfig.class]
    - spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties: defined in null`

Seems like spring boot found 2 DataSourceProperties for the constructor DataSourceInitializerInvoker, i am not sure why, because i have only the one class that you have but when i mark my Configuration as Primary it works.

```
@Configuration 
@Primary
public class SpringConfigurationProperties extends DataSourceProperties {
...

}
```

Additional for Comment .properties:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=test

gps.bulk.load.database.url=test
gps.bulk.load.database.username=test
gps.bulk.load.database.password=test
gps.bulk.load.database.driver-class-name=test

Comment: I had tried that at one point, but after some other configuration changes, yes this did get me past that error, but now I am getting:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.  I have in my properties, and this was working with one DS, gps.prio.database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@...

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter'

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required

Comment: But `gps.prio.database.url` is not your datasource it should be `gps.bulk.load.database.url` and `spring.datasource.url` or ? (I edit my answer)

Comment: yea sorry that was another datasource that is still in the prop file just copied the wrong one to this thread.  I got past the issues of start up, but no matter what I do, the secondary datasource always picks up the spring.datasource and ignores the override of @ConfigurationProperties...