# Is there a way to use a repository without applying repository base class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application annotated with `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = CommonRepository.class)`.
Almost all of the repositories need to implement some custom logic which is done using `repositoryBaseClass`.

Is there a way to create a repository that will be excluded from `repositoryBaseClass` mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a repository that doesn't implement one of the Spring Data JPA `Repository` interfaces. Essentially you would write a repository like you would do without Spring Data JPA.

```
public class YourRepo /* No Spring Data interface here! */ { 

    @Autowired
    private EntityManger entityManager;

    public add(Something entity) {
        entityManager.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you would need to [create different configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663025/spring-data-jpa-multiple-enablejparepositories) (with `@Configuration`) if you you want to use different `repositoryBaseClass`es.

Comment: And probably adjust component scan, so the `Configuration` with `repositoryBaseClass = CommonRepository.class` doesn't pick up the specific other `Repository`

Comment: huh, yes, the idea of not using spring for something didn't occur to me :)