# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'commandGateway' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon

I am upgrading my existing axon-core :  3.3.6  to 4.0.4 and facing the issue while building the application how may I resolve it?

Here is the exception:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'commandGateway' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/axonframework/springboot/autoconfig/AxonAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'commandGateway'
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandBus'
> available: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates:
> [commandBus, distributedCommandBus]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002892/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-javax-sql-datasource-available-more-than-one-prim)

Comment: Sorry https://stackoverflow.com/users/15153326/mohamed-bdr that doesn't work here, it's something related to axon commandbus but the link you shared is for Database. I am not sure whether this suits appropriate answer here.

Comment: no problem, I found ` more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates` in error so I tried to think that maybe it is because of that error. hope that you will find the answer soon

Answer (score 3):

The shared exception mentions:

> more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [commandBus,
> distributedCommandBus]

This probably means that you have your `CommandBus` bean annotated with `@Primary`. If so, you can remove that annotation, as the `DistributedCommandBus` instance is the one that should act as primary only.

If this is not the case, you can resolve the issue by explicitly configuring a `CommandGateway`. That way, you override Axon's auto configuration, which apparently has difficulties resolving "the" Command Bus to use. The class you'd be looking to construct is the `DefaultCommandGateway`, which takes a reference to the `CommandBus` to which it acts as a gateway. You will probably want to inject the `DistributedCommandBus`.

As a last remark, Axon has already progressed to version 4.5. A lot of improvements have been made along the way that may be worthwhile. It is also nu unlikely that some of the auto configuration issues you're bumping into have been addressed in some intermediate version.