# How to setup multiple Spring Data JPA with different base-packages,transactionManagerRef using class based configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In our current XML based configuration, we have setup for multiple repositories like below:

```
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.grc.riskanalysis.repository.master" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.grc.riskanalysis.repository.slave" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager2"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="dynamicEntityManagerFactory"/>
```

I am trying to migrate this XML configuration to class based configuration, but it is not allowing to have multiple @EnableJpaRepositories annotations. How to achieve this with class based (annotation based) configuration ?

Comment: You can have as many `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotations as you want, just place them on seperate `@Configuration` classes. That way you can also seperate the different JPA configurations for the datasource/txmanager/entitymanagerfactory.

Comment: Yes, I found same solution in below links( mentioned in my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from the below two posts, seems need to write separate configuration class for each JPA.

[baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)

[Enable Multiple JPA Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663025/spring-data-jpa-multiple-enablejparepositories)

Answer (score 2):

`@EnableJpaRepositories` has a parameter named `basePackages`. It accepts an array of strings and you can use that to add your packages.

Something like the following will do

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"package1", "package2"})`