# A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, rest, postman

I am doing a project in SpringBoot using Postgres and restful approach. My application is failing to start.I am new to this.Please help me with this problem.Below is my code:

***Error***

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.4.2-SNAPSHOT)

2020-12-30 21:42:08.397  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] com.cg.pps.SpringRestApplication         : Starting SpringRestApplication using Java 15.0.1 on DESKTOP-7ODO40V with PID 7284 (D:\E drive\studymaterial\Sprint2\PersonalityPredictionSystemMus\target\classes started by BST in D:\E drive\studymaterial\Sprint2\PersonalityPredictionSystemMus)
2020-12-30 21:42:08.410  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] com.cg.pps.SpringRestApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-30 21:42:08.677  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-12-30 21:42:08.678  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-12-30 21:42:10.722  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-12-30 21:42:10.921  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 165 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-12-30 21:42:12.831  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:12.848  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'relProviderPluginRegistry' of type [org.springframework.plugin.core.support.PluginRegistryFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:12.896  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'relProviderPluginRegistry' of type [org.springframework.plugin.core.OrderAwarePluginRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:12.907  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '_relProvider' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.DelegatingLinkRelationProvider] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:12.933  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'messageResolver' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.MessageSourceResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:12.936  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataJacksonConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataJacksonConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:12.952  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonGeoModule' of type [org.springframework.data.geo.GeoModule] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.002  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.011  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.018  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.097  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.100  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration$StandardJackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.106  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.112  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'parameterNamesModule' of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.114  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.137  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jsonComponentModule' of type [org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonComponentModule] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.145  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.165  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.data.rest-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.166  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'springBootRepositoryRestConfigurer' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestConfigurer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.169  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurerDelegate' of type [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerDelegate] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.185  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.204  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'stringHttpMessageConverter' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.207  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.210  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.224  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.279  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonObjectMapper' of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.284  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:13.286  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-30 21:42:14.804  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8082 (http)
2020-12-30 21:42:14.840  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-30 21:42:14.841  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2020-12-30 21:42:15.409  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-30 21:42:15.410  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6731 ms
2020-12-30 21:42:16.076  WARN 7284 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cvRepo' defined in com.cg.pps.repository.CvRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on SpringRestApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2fe84e0e' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2fe84e0e': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2020-12-30 21:42:16.089  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-12-30 21:42:16.173  INFO 7284 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-12-30 21:42:16.308 ERROR 7284 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

**App.java**

```java
    package com.cg.pps;
    
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
    
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.cg.pps.repository"})
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringRestApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringRestApplication.class, args);
        }
        
        
    }
```

**Controller**

```java
    package com.cg.pps.controller;
    import java.util.List;
    
    
    import com.cg.pps.model.*;
    import com.cg.pps.service.*;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    @RestController()
    @RequestMapping("/candidatecv")
    public class CandidateCvController {
         @Autowired
          private CandidateCvs candidatecvs;
         @GetMapping("/getall")
         public List<CandidateCv> getAllPeople() {
             return candidatecvs.getAllCandiateCv();
         }
         
         @GetMapping("/get/{id}")
         public CandidateCv getCandidateCvByEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
             return candidatecvs.getCandidateCvByEmail(email);
         }
         @PostMapping("/create")
         public String createCandidateCv(@PathVariable CandidateCv cv) {
    
             if(cv != null) {
                candidatecvs.createCandidateCv(cv);
                 return "Cv Added";
             } else {
                 return "Request does not contain a body";
             }
         }
        
    
    }
```

**model**

```java
    package com.cg.pps.model;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    
    
    
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    
    
    
    //import the job package
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name="cand_info")
    public class CandidateCv implements Serializable {
        
        @Id
        @Column(name="CandidateName", length=20)
        private String CandidateName;   
        @Column(name="Email",length=12 ,unique=true)
        private String email;
        @Column(name="Phoneno",length=10)
        private int phoneno;
        @Column(name="Qualification",length=10)
        private String qualification;
        @Column(name="Experience",length=2)
        private int exp;
        @Column(name="Skill",length=10)
        private String skill;
        public CandidateCv() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        
    
        public CandidateCv(String candidateName, String email, int phoneno, String qualification, int exp, String skill) {
            super();
            CandidateName = candidateName;
            this.email = email;
            this.phoneno = phoneno;
            this.qualification = qualification;
            this.exp = exp;
            this.skill = skill;
        }
        
        public String getCandidateName() {
            return CandidateName;
        }
        public void setCandidateName(String candidateName) {
            CandidateName = candidateName;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public int getPhoneno() {
            return phoneno;
        }
        public void setPhoneno(int phoneno) {
            this.phoneno = phoneno;
        }
        public String getQualification() {
            return qualification;
        }
        public void setQualification(String qualification) {
            this.qualification = qualification;
        }
        public int getExp() {
            return exp;
        }
        public void setExp(int exp) {
            this.exp = exp;
        }
        public String getSkill() {
            return skill;
        }
        public void setSkill(String skill) {
            this.skill = skill;
        }
        
    }
```

**Repository**

```java
    package com.cg.pps.repository;
    
    import com.cg.pps.model.CandidateCv;
    
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    
    @Repository
    public interface CvRepo extends CrudRepository<CandidateCv, Long> {
        public boolean existByEmail(String email);
        public CandidateCv findByEmail(String email);
    }
```

**ServiceInterface**

```java
    package com.cg.pps.service;
    
    import com.cg.pps.model.*;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    
    
    public interface CandidateCvs {
    
        List<CandidateCv> getAllCandiateCv();
        CandidateCv getCandidateCvByEmail(String email);
        String createCandidateCv(CandidateCv e);
        
    
    }

**Service Implementation**

    package com.cg.pps.service;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    import javax.transaction.Transactional;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import com.cg.pps.repository.CvRepo;
    
    import com.cg.pps.model.CandidateCv;
    
    @Transactional
    @Service
    public class CandidateCvImpl implements CandidateCvs {
        
        private CvRepo repository;
    
        @Override
        public List<CandidateCv> getAllCandiateCv() {
            return (List<CandidateCv>)repository.findAll();
        }
    
        @Override
        public String createCandidateCv(CandidateCv e) {
            
          String id=e.getEmail();
            if(repository.existByEmail(id)) 
        {
                return "Candidate Cv already exists";
                }
        else {
                repository.save(e);
                return "Employee data successfully saved";
            }
            
            
            
            
            
        }
    
        @Override
        public CandidateCv getCandidateCvByEmail(String email) {
            CandidateCv cv= new CandidateCv();
              String id=cv.getEmail();
                if(repository.existByEmail(id)) {
                    return repository.findByEmail(email);
            
                    }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
                
        }
    
        
    }
```

**Pom.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>demo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       
      
        
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

Please review my above codes and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you excluding "DataSourceAutoConfiguration"? Remove @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}) from your main class. Actually you do not need these two @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.cg.pps.repository"}). For more info please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416927/spring-boot-required-a-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-that-could-not-be-foun/54663039

Comment: @P.Sanjay when I removed these lines.It is giving me a new error (Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor ).Above I have included my Pom.xml file too

Comment: Are you doing manual configuration for JPA? If yes, then you need to define your bean with entity manage factory like this @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    return sessionFactory;
} If still there is problem, then looks like there is some problem with your datasource configuration. please provide your db configs. Also did you check the link which i had mentioned in my previous commnet.

Comment: @P.Sanjay I got the error. It was in Repository file.In this method (public boolean existByEmail(String email);).The definition of this method was wrong. I replaced it with this.   @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(u) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END FROM CandidateCv u WHERE u.email = ?1")
    public Boolean existsByEmail(String email);