# Spring boot JPA does not create table in h2 DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm developing a spring boot app and use JPA.

I'm trying to run the app and this error occurs:
[image]

Main:
[image: Main:]

Entity:
[image: Entity:]

Repository:
[image: Repository]

application.properties:
[image]

DB properties:
[image]

Comment: Might the property for the password just have a typo in your application.properties? It should not be springspring.datasource.password..

Comment: where is your Entities? what you expect to happen when haven't any entity?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416927/spring-boot-required-a-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-that-could-not-be-foun/54663039. This might solve the problem.

Comment: `springspring.datasource.password` is the wrong statement. Can you share your `pom.xml`? I guess something is wrong with your dependencies.