# Application failed to start due to an exception: "Description: A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found."

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying to follow this guide [here](https://www.heise.de/hintergrund/Webentwicklung-Mit-Spring-und-Kotlin-eine-To-do-Liste-programmieren-6663170.html?seite=all) with slight deviations, but somehow my application doesn't start.

It's a Gradle-based build using Spring Boot and Kotlin.
The deviation I've mentioned before is I've configured it to use a Postgres-Db inside a Docker container instead of the H2-Db.

Here my build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

  plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "8.5.12"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.6.21"
 }

 group = "com.snixtodolist"
 version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
 java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.1.0.Final")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")

    // only for tests
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
 }

 tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
     }
 }

 tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
 }

flyway {

    locations = arrayOf("db/migration/ALL")

    target = "001"
    baselineVersion = "001"

    /** Use for PostGreSQL (local, Docker) */
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/snixtodolist" // local (PostGreSQL)
    user = "snix"
    password = "password"

}

tasks.flywayMigrate{
    dependsOn(tasks.assemble)
}
```

Here my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/snixtodolist
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.sql.init.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.username=snix
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.postgresql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

The error message I'm receiving is the follwoing:

```
2022-06-14 09:13:51.920 DEBUG 91518 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : Application failed to start due to an exception

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:872) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:510) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:934) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at com.snixtodolist.snixtodolist.SnixtodolistApplicationKt.main(SnixtodolistApplication.kt:22) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
```

It can't relate to WHY this is even needed in the first place:
"No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available"?

All my repos are clearly annotated as "@Entity",
and in the included test, see below, I've tried to trigger it directly as "@Autowired" as a last bandage. Before that it wasn't entered at all, like specified in the guide.

```
package com.snixtodolist.snixtodolist.adapter.jpa

import com.snixtodolist.snixtodolist.domain.Task
import com.snixtodolist.snixtodolist.domain.TaskRepository
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneOffset
import javax.persistence.EntityManager
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
class TaskRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var repository: TaskRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var entityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory

    @Autowired
    lateinit var em: EntityManager

    @Test
    fun shouldPersistTask(
        entityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory,
    ) {
        val date = LocalDateTime.of(
            2022, 6, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0
        ).atOffset(
            ZoneOffset.systemDefault()
                .rules
                .getOffset(LocalDateTime.now())
        )
        val taskToSave = Task(
            id = 0,
            created_on = date,
            title = "Streichen",
            dueDate = date,
            isDone = true,
        )

        val savedTask= repository.save(taskToSave)
        em.flush()
        em.clear()

        val taskFromDb =
            repository.findById(savedTask.id)
                .orElseThrow()

        assertThat(savedTask.title).isEqualTo(taskToSave.title)
        assertThat(savedTask.id).isNotEqualTo(0)
        assertEquals(date, taskFromDb.dueDate)
        assertTrue(taskFromDb.isDone)
    }

}
```

I'm out of options, I've tried several hints from stackoverflow pages,
but I can't get it to work.

Please help!

Comment: There is similar question already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416927/spring-boot-required-a-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-that-could-not-be-foun

Comment: I've seen this before, but his build does include way more functionality.
I've only implemented a repo request in the test and it is already unable to create the Bean it should based on the Spring annotations.