# Field userRepository in com.x.x.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.x.x.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

Good morning ! despite all my research I can not solve this problem with application spring someone can help me I use jdk 17;

My Service class

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

@Autowired
public UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public void save(UserModel user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
}
@Override
public void update(UserModel user) {

}
@Override
public UserModel load(UserModel user) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<UserModel> loadByMultiple(String data) {
    return null;//userRepository.loadByMultiple(data);
}


@Override
public UserModel loadByUsername(String username) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public UserModel loadByEmail(String email) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public UserModel loadByPhone(String phone) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void delete(UserModel user) {

}
}
```

My Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserModel, Long> {

/*@Query("""
        SELECT u FROM user u WHERE u.user_name LIKE % :data% or  u.last_name = LIKE % :data%
         """)
List<UserModel> loadByMultiple(@Param("data") String data);*/
```

}

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DecouverteBackendApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DecouverteBackendApplication.class, args);
}

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.6.7
 

com.infinitylogic
Decouverte_backend
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Decouverte_backend
Decouverte_backend

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.hibernate
hibernate-core
5.2.1.Final


org.hibernate
hibernate-entitymanager
5.2.3.Final

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.200</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My project structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aov7s.png)

Comment: How does your package structure exactly look like? Is your main class in a common super package of all other classes?

Comment: You can now see my project struture below.

Answer (score 0):

When the repository package is different to @SpringBootApplication/@EnableAutoConfiguration, base package of @EnableJpaRepositories is required to be defined explicitly.

Try to add @EnableJpaRepositories("your.package.structure.here") to DecouverteBackendApplication

Comment: By @EnableJpaRepositories or @EnableJpaRepositories("com.package.structure.repository") i get the error message . Field userRepository in com.infinitylogic.decouverte_backend.UserServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
 Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration

Comment: Add @EnableAutoConfiguration to your main class. If it does not help, see other solutions here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520602/spring-data-jpa-no-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-is-defined-injection-of-a

Answer (score -1):

Try this (using Lombok's `RequiredArgsConstructor`):

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

private final UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public void save(UserModel user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
}
...
```