SpringBoot project working with Intellij but not in a docker container
(I'm using Kotlin) I have a SpringBoot project which is running perfectly fine when I start it with Intellij Idea. But I need to have it running with Docker and when it's compilation time I get this type of error :
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'plantController' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/build/libs/Back-end-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar!/fr/arosaje/controller/PlantController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'plantService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/build/libs/Back-end-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar!/fr/arosaje/service/PlantService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'plantRepository' defined in fr.arosaje.repository.PlantRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Main: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:959)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
backend-1  |    at fr.arosaje.MainKt.main(Main.kt:17)
backend-1  | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'plantService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/build/libs/Back-end-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar!/fr/arosaje/service/PlantService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'plantRepository' defined in fr.arosaje.repository.PlantRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Main: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:907)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:785)
backend-1  |    ... 18 common frames omitted
backend-1  | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'plantRepository' defined in fr.arosaje.repository.PlantRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Main: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1685)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1434)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:907)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:785)
backend-1  |    ... 32 common frames omitted
backend-1  | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:685)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
backend-1  |    ... 46 common frames omitted
backend-1  | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
backend-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
backend-1  |    ... 58 common frames omitted

Here is my docker-compose and the run.sh:
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    image: openjdk:19-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./Back-end:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: sh ./run.sh
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - sqlite
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:sqlite:sqlite/db

  sqlite:
    image: alpine:latest
    volumes:
      - ./sqlite:/sqlite
    command: sh -c "apk --no-cache add sqlite && touch /sqlite/db && sqlite3 /sqlite/db && tail -f /dev/null"
    container_name: sqlite

#!/bin/sh
apk update && apk add findutils
./gradlew clean build
java -jar $(ls -1 build/libs/*.jar | head -n 1)

Here is my build.gradle.kts :
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.22"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.9.22"
    java
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.0"
}

group = "fr.arosaje"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.2")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.2")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.2")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.3.0")
    implementation("org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.44.1.0")
    implementation("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects:6.2.7.Final")
    implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {
    archiveClassifier.set("fat")
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "fr.arosaje.MainKt"
    }
}

tasks.build {
    dependsOn(tasks.withType<ShadowJar>())
}

configure<org.springframework.boot.gradle.dsl.SpringBootExtension> {
    springBoot {
        mainClass.set("fr.arosaje.MainKt")
    }
}

I tried changing jdk version from 17 to 19 because my image was 17 and my project running in 19 (changed nothing) and I couldnt find anything else

Please add the full stacktrace, there should be more information.

I added the full stacktrace.

I would expect more information to be in there. One thing why did you define an @EnableJpaRepositories on your Main class. Generally that shouldn't be necessary with Spring Boot.

I copy/paste all I had in the console. Also for the @EnableJpaRepositories i tried deleting it and I have some new errors, but i don't know if we're going forward or backward

As mentioned generally you shouldn't need it, so the fact that you needed to add it already is some indication you are doing something in not the most efficient way. What I also don't get is why run a build each time you want to start the container, that is really inefficient imho.

I am kind of unused to docker which is maybe why I am doing things I shouldn't, I am still learning. I rebuild it everytime because I'm often going to do some changes in the project, I could be thinking it the wrong way.

Does this page provide a clue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520602/spring-data-jpa-no-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-is-defined-injection-of-a

If you are doing a lot of changes, why use Docker in the first place?

Because its a project I need to do and I need to make it run with docker so I wanted to do it now so i'm already done with this part

I briefly checked link but it does not seems to help me

Try running the jar locally with
java -jar ${pathToYourJar}
If it runs, you're good to go, if it doesn't (most likely the case) you need to add the spring plugin to build the fat jar.
Also please share your pom.xml
