# Error : No persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

i'm trying to start my understanding of Hibernate . But I have a problem.
With my researches I found lots of things but nothing to fix my issues..
"org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence is written in red color.

My persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="demojpa">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

            <!-- Configuration de la BDD -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/demojpa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

            <!-- Specifie le dialecte SQL utilisé pour communiquer avec la BDD -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect"/>

            <!-- Indique a Hibernate de re-creer la BDD au lancement de l'applciation -->
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

my class

```
public class DemoJpa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1 Ouverture unité de travail JPA
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("demojpa");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

To finish a picture of my root...
Because I think there is a problem in this one....

[image: My root]

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your `persistence.xml` replace the *[deprecated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence.html)* declaration (removed in Hibernate versions 5+)

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

with

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Basically, this should make the "red color" disappear.

Notice well, that Hibernate in version 4.3.x [supports JPA 2.1](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/) (see the table *Supported JPA Versions*). Important: You should also declare in the head of the persistence.xml the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
```

This will give you full JPA 2.1 support and tell the ORM to make use of version 2.1.

As you're just getting started, better start with Hibernate in version [5.2](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.2/) or above, as these releases will be supported longer than 4.3.x which is already considered "maintenance only" and no longer actively improved or developed for.

For reference, the [persistence provider deprecation topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21693139/2849346) has been discussed earlier.

Hope it helps.